# Persistent Volume Mount Causes App install to hang

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes

I have am using the follwoing volume claim:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: persistent-storage-claim
  labels:
    app: {{ include "api-chart.name" . }}
    chart: {{ include "api-chart.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  storageClassName: managed-premium
  volumeName: personal
```

in the following deployment:

```
...
...
 spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registrySecret
      volumes:
        - name: personal-volume
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: persistent-storage-claim
      containers:
        - name: container1
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.service.targetPort }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: personal-volume
              mountPath: "/workspace"
...
```

Mounting this volume seems to cause the deployment to hang (it does not deploy, but there are no error messages that I can see anywhere). If the `volumenMounts` part is removed, the deployment succeeds. 
I am using `helm install` to deploy the app. Any ideas as to what might be causing the problem? Or at least how to debug this?

Update: 
`kubectl get events`
returns the following:

```
LAST SEEN   TYPE      REASON              OBJECT                                                                             MESSAGE
46s         Warning   FailedScheduling    pod/storage-test-labd62r2                pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)
24m         Normal    SuccessfulCreate    replicaset/test-storage-b65db5698   Created pod: storage-test-labd62r2
24m         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet   deployment/test-storage            Scaled up replica set test-storage-b65db5698 to 1
24m         Normal    CREATE              ingress/test-storage               Ingress default/test-storage
24m         Normal    CREATE              ingress/test-storage               Ingress default/test-storage
24m         Normal    UPDATE              ingress/test-storage               Ingress default/test-storage
24m         Normal    UPDATE              ingress/test-storage               Ingress default/test-storage
```

and `kubectl get pvc` gives:

```
NAME                       STATUS    VOLUME                    CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS      AGE
persistent-storage-claim   Pending   personal                  0                         managed-premium   33m
```

`kubectl get pv` displays nothing

`kubectl svc`:

```
NAME                                                          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
test-storage   ClusterIP   10.0.244.147   <none>        80/TCP,8080/TCP   35m
kubernetes                                                    ClusterIP   10.0.0.1       <none>        443/TCP           16d
```

Comment: share output of kubectl get pv,pvc,sc and kubectl describe deploymentname  and kubectl get events

Comment: Can you share how do you mount the PVC on the deployment? And give the output of command `kubectl describe pvc`?

Comment: You have specified storageclassname in your pvc, did you change your default storageclass to this new one called managed-premium? Based on [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-default-storage-class/#why-change-the-default-storage-class) `Depending on the installation method, your Kubernetes cluster may be deployed with an existing StorageClass that is marked as default. This default StorageClass is then used to dynamically provision storage for PersistentVolumeClaims that do not require any specific storage class`

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens because there is no manually provisioned `PersistentVolume` to satisfy the `PersistentVolumeClaim` or the `StorageClass` mentioned in the claim does not exist or could not dynamically provision a `PersistentVolume` to satisfy the `PersistentVolumeClaim`

Comment: It seems as though the storage class does exist. Although, is it possible that it is not enabled? Or configured properly? Is there any other obvious reason why the dynamic provisioning would not work?

Comment: Yes, it is an AKS cluster.

Comment: Could be a permission issue..is this first time you are provisioning volume in this cluster?https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/485

Comment: Yes, first dynamic provisioning (static provisions have worked previously). Thank you,I will investigate this further.